# I want to save data to a json file from a python program for a stock management program

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a simple stock management program as a learning exercise but I can't seem to find a way to save the changes I make while the program is open to a file. Here is the python code.

```
import json
with open('Stock.json') as json_data:
    stock = json.load(json_data)


def menu():
    print("Press 1: To add stock. ")
    print("Press 2: To check stock. ")
    print("press 3: To enter purchase. ")
    print("Press 4: To quit the program. ")
    return input("What would you like to do? ")

run = menu()

while True:
    if run == '1':
        AddStock = input('Product to be added to stock? ')
        Amount = int(input('Quantity of product to be added to stock? '))
        stock[AddStock] = Amount
        run = menu()

    elif run == '2':
        for key, value in stock.items():
            print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
        run = menu()

    elif run == '3':
        product = input('What product was sold? ')
        if product in stock:
                stock[product] -= 1
        else:
            print("Product is out of stock! ")
        run = menu()

    elif run == '4':
        break
```

And then there is the .json file I am trying to write to

```
{
    "stock": {
        "Apples": 100,
        "Bananas": 150,
        "Berries": 200,
        "Oranges": 50
    }

}
```

The program runs fine without any problems, especially when I was just using a python dictionary instead of the json file, the only problem is that it won't write to memory so when I close the program I lose any data I entered when it was open.

Comment: I see no attempt to write to a file...

Comment: Fyi, use snake case for your variables.
In your code, you should write stock[add_stock] = amount
Useally Pascal case is for class names.

Comment: Btw, if you want to add stock, just do += not =

Comment: A little different approach that helps separate data (descriptions and actions) from process (printing the menu and inputting the selection).  https://repl.it/I1xP/10

Comment: @J.McGinley were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

When you load from a file and parse it using json you get a dict/list.  You are then working with it but you don't write it back to the file.  I'm guessing you would want to do that when exiting.  Something like:

```
with open('Stock.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(stock, json_file, indent=4)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump

Answer (score 0):

Say "data" is the variable you want to write and update on each iteration then we use "wb" as used in the code below to write json file.

```
with open("stock.json", "wb") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file as binary?  When I do that in my rewrite of the code i get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.  https://repl.it/I1xP/11

Comment: it works in python 2.7 whereas i guess it has some issues with 3.5, So you can replace 'wb' with 'w'. or to appen you can use 'a', this will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, Python 2 strings are bytes not Unicode.  Seems to me that in Python 2 there ought to be handling of the encoding somewhere.  Say you have some non-ascii characters in the product name, what encoding should be used to turn them into bytes?  If you don't need to explicitly specify this where is it being handled implicitly?  Also note the OP is likely Python 3 code due to the parentheses with prints and the int() conversion of the input() result.